# Strugling to connect Nextjs 13 front end to existing Flask backend

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

To preface, this is the first project I've made using next, and I'm overall pretty new to full stack development. I cant for the life of me figure out how to get next to reach my backend flask app. I really wanted to try next because all of the features seem really awesome, but Im on the verge of going back to Vite because it makes this stuff easy.

An example of the issue, I'm trying to get information stored in a database that my flask app routes too. If I go to the flask apps route in a browser, lets say http://localhost:5000/facility/facilities the browser displays all of my facility information correctly in json format like so

```
  {    
    "address": "address example", 
    "building": "Random example building",
    "calendar_id": "example@resources.calendar",
    "id": 19,
    "image_path": "path/to/image.jpg",
    "name": "Facility Name"  
 },
```

With my app folder structured like this : .

```
├── calendar
│   └── page.tsx
├── components
│   └── navbar
│       ├── Navbar.tsx
│       └── login.tsx
├── facilities
│   ├── [facility]
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── facility_card.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
├── favicon.ico
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
├── page.tsx
├── redux
├── scripts
│   └── darkmode.js
├── types
│   └── index.ts
└── users
    └── [user]
```

and my page.tsx in my facilities folder like this:

```js
import FacilityCard from './facility_card';

import { Facility } from '../types/index'; import  {GetServerSideProps}  from 'next';

interface FacilitiesPageProps {

facilities: Facility[]; }

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
 try {
   const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/facility/facilities');
   if (!res.ok) {
     throw new Error('Something went wrong ${res.status}'); 
     console.log(res);     } const facilities: Facility[] = await res.json();

console.log('Received facilities:', facilities); 

return {

props: { facilities,       },     };   } catch (err) { console.error('Error fetching facilities:', err); // Add this line return { props: { facilities: [],       },     };   } };

const FacilitiesPage: React.FC<FacilitiesPageProps> = ({ facilities }) => {

return (

 <div>
  <h1>Facilities</h1>
    <ul> 
        {facilities && facilities.length > 0 ? (
          facilities.map((facility) => (
            <FacilityCard key={facility.id} facility={facility.name} />
           ))
         ) : (
            <p>No facilities found</p>
         )}
     </ul>
 </div>
  );
}

export default FacilitiesPage;
```

All my page does is display No facilities found, neither the console in the browser dev tools nor the terminal my app is running in make any indication that its trying to fetch the data.

I know this is a huge post but I'm very lost and definitely considering throwing in the towel on Next

I've tried tried calling multiple different routes in a similar fashion but nothing happens. The console gives no indication that an attempt getting server side props is even happening